# Sort list of PropertyInfos by property value of its attribute

Tags: c#, linq, properties, attributes

I have an `Dto` object of type:

```
public class ClassA
{       
    [DataMember(Order = 10)]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 20)]
    public string Symbology { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 30)]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    public string NonMemberPropertyA { get; set; }
}
```

I am interested in obtaining all the `DataMember` decorated properties:

```
 var propertyInfos = type.GetProperties().Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof (DataMemberAttribute)));
```

Now I need to sort my `propertyInfos` based on the `Order`property of the `DataMember` attribute. Because some might be out of order.

So I tried to add:

```
.OrderBy(p => ((DataFormat)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(p, typeof (DataFormat))).Order);
```

But I get *"cannot be inferred from usage"* error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working using this:

```
var orders = a1
    .GetType()
    .GetProperties()
    .Where(x => Attribute.IsDefined(x, typeof(DataMemberAttribute)))
    .Select(x => new { Att = x.GetCustomAttribute<DataMemberAttribute>(true), Prop = x })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Att.Order);
```

The `Select()` projects an anonymous object comprising of the property itself and the attribute so that you can then order by the attribute.

`a1` is an instance of your object `ClassA`

I modified your code and got it working:

```
var orders = a1
    .GetType()
    .GetProperties()
    .Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(DataMemberAttribute)))
    .OrderBy(p => ((DataMemberAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(p, typeof(DataMemberAttribute))).Order);
```

Comment: copy cat! just kidding.

Comment: tbh using linq there aren't many different ways of doing this! hence our answers are similar. One thing i noticed with yours though was that changing `BindingFlags.NonPublic` to `BindingFlags.Instance` fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
var propertyInfos = type
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataMemberAttribute), false).Length > 0)
            .SelectMany(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<DataMemberAttribute>())
            .OrderBy(m => m.Order)
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: DataMember should be replaced with DataMemberAttribute